# Create two set of mutually exclusive random samples in python

Tags: python, random, numpy

I have two different numpy.array A[m,n] and B[m,p]. I want to create two random samples from both A and B respectively, i.e. A1[m1,n], A2[m2,n] and B1[m1,p], B2[m2,p].

Or specifically if I take two random samples of index corresponding to rows, i.e.

```
rnd1 = [random.randint(1,m) for r in xrange(m1)]
rnd2 = [random.randint(1,m) for r in xrange(m2)]
```

and try to create the sub arrays as

```
A1=[A[i,:] for i in rnd1]
A2=[A[i,:] for i in rnd2]
```

and

```
B1=[B[i,:] for i in rnd1]
B2=[B[i,:] for i in rnd2]
```

The sequence of rows in A1 and B1 are same, similarly sequence of rows same for A2 and B2 also. But rand1 and rnd2 are not mutually exclusive.

How to create mutually exclusive sets ?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. Do you have any trouble implementing this? Where exactly? What have you tried? This isn't a write-my-code-for-me site.

Comment: "Such that the sequence of rows in A1 and B1 are same, similarly same for A2 and B2 also." - what does that mean? The interpretation I'm coming up with - each row of A1 being equal to the corresponding row of B1, and each row of A2 being equal to the corresponding row of B2 - simplifies to A1 and A2 having identical contents to B1 and B2. That won't generally be possible.

Comment: I have edited the question and added more description and some code snippets to help understand the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one way to do that is to assign each index in the range `[0, m - 1]` to `idx1` series or `idx2` series with equal probabilities, and then sample from `idx1` and `idx2`:

```
m, m1, m2 = 10, 5, 7

# tag each index with equal probabilities to True & False
# note: p = m1 / ( m1 + m2 ) can make more sense depending
# on desired distribution
tag = np.random.binomial(n=1, p=.5, size=m) == 1

# assign True indices to idx1 and False indices to index 2
idx = np.array( range( m ) )
idx1, idx2 = idx[ tag ], idx[ np.logical_not( tag ) ]

# sample from idx1 and idx2
i1, i2 = np.random.choice( idx1, size=m1 ), np.random.choice( idx2, size=m2 )
```

the only caveat is that you need to redo the tagging until `sum( tag ) != 0` and `sum( tag ) != ml`; that is `idx1` and `idx2` are non-empty.

*you may also set `p=m1/(m1+m2)` in above, depending on the distribution you are looking for.*